# Como ler e separar em bloco esse TXT com PHP?

Tags: php, txt

Como posso ler um arqui TXT nesse formato para inserir numa tabela de episódios? A estrutura é essa:

```
temporada{
    numero_episodio - nome_do_episodio
}
```

Um exemplo prático:

```
1{
    1 - Episódio número 1 na 1ª Temporada
    2 - Episódio número 2 na 1ª Temporada
    ...
}
2{
    1 - Episódio número 1 na 2ª Temporada
    2 - Episódio número 2 na 2ª Temporada
    ...
}
```

Como percorrer, ler e separar essas linhas de forma que ficasse um array no seguinte formato: `episodios[temporada][episodio][nome_do_episodio]`, é possível? Existe alguma forma mais fácil de organizar esse TXT?

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência com as funções preg_split e preg_match, consegue me dar um exemplo prático de como aplicá-las ao meu exemplo?

Comment: Fiquei com uma duvida Leo, esse formato você quem inventou? Já ouviu falar de JSON? Eu realmente não sei se compensa criar uma parse próprio quando se pode usar um formato mais utilizado ;)

Comment: Algumas vezes será necessário adicionar uma grande quantidade de episódios de uma única vez, esse foi o formato mais fácil que encontrei para os outros usuários adicionarem mais linhas de uma única vez, vou ainda criar um formulário para tal, mas quero deixar essa opção disponível também, mas irei verificar a possibilidade usar json

Comment: Deixar tal operação para o usuário modificar manualmente é um baita risco. Por mais simples e intuitivo que faça o formato o usuário vai conseguir estragar na maioria das vezes.

Comment: É apenas outra pessoa além de mim, seria útil pois muitas vezes precisamos deixar os episódios prontos para serem inseridos, porém não queremos eles no banco de dados ainda, por isso seria útil te-los separados em um TxT, mas vou deixar apenas um formulário com campos dinâmicos.

Comment: Você já pensou em inserir eles no sistema e simplesmente deixar como ativo ou inativo?

Comment: Vou pensar melhor sobre, e verei com a outra pessoa se ele realmente quer uma maneira tão mais simples assim a ponto de não puder usar um formulário para tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se são apenas duas pessoas que irão editar o DOC não tem nada melhor que usar um formato mais "exato" como JSON ou XML, ao invés de inventar seu próprio formato, de qualquer forma uma maneira +ou- simples é com expressões regulares e replace, demorei um pouco mas consegui criar um exemplo:

```
<?php

function converteParaJson($str) {
    //Primeiro iremos converter fazer um parser para JSON +ou- assim:

    //Cria as temporadas
    $str = preg_replace('#^(|\s)+(\d+)(\s|)\{#', '"$2": {', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('#\}(\s|)+(\d+)\{#', '}, "$2": {', $str);

    //Cria os episódios
    $str = preg_replace('#(\d+)(\s+|)\-(\s+|)([^\r\n]+)#', '"$1": "$4",', $str);

    //Remove virgulas extras
    $str = preg_replace('#,[\s]+\}#', '}', $str);

    $str = '{' . $str . '}';

    return $str;
}

$txt = '1{
    1 - Episódio número 1 na 1ª Temporada
    2 - Episódio número 2 na 1ª Temporada
}
2{
    1 - Episódio número 1 na 2ª Temporada
    2 - Episódio número 2 na 2ª Temporada
}';

$txt = converteParaJson($txt);

//Converte o json para array do php
$data = json_decode($txt, true);

print_r($data);
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/SEwPqz

Comment: Vai funcionar mesmo que tenha mais que duas temporadas? Obrigado pelo exemplo Guilherme, vou tomar como exemplo pra estudar melhor o preg_replace

Comment: @LeoLetto funciona sim, por isso tem 2 `preg_replace`s para as temporadas, aonde eu escrevi `//Cria as temporadas`, um é para primeira temporada e outro para as demais independente da quantidade. Se algo falhar me avise